# How to style Font Awesome in HTML document

Tags: css, fonts, colors, font-size, font-awesome

Hi would like to adjust the font-size and color on font awesome.  This is the code I am using and I can either get the color or the font-size to work.  But not both together. Also not sure if I should use in-line CSS or create a separate CSS file.  It's a short HTML form (calculator).

```
<i class="fa fa-venus" style="font-size:32px"; color:pink></i>
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?  I have done extensive searching and can't seem to find the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: you have a typo in your style, move the " to the end of pink, and add a ; after pink

use a IDE to help you with the syntax

Comment: font awesome is just used like a font, what ever you can change to any font can be change in the same manner with font awesome, nothing special here. The magic is with the vector images and the css they provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, `color` property should be inside quotes

```
<i class="fa fa-venus" style="font-size:32px; color:pink;"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you, Muhammet.  
I ended up using this and it worked as well.

In the header:
<style>
<style>i.medium {font-size: 4em;} </style>
</style>

In the body:   <i class="fa fa-venus medium" style="color:fuchsia"></i>